# lightning:input (date) change format to dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, date-picker, lightninginput

The lightning input field has an attribute "pattern". What pattern should i use? I've already tried "mm/dd/yyyy" but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [pattern](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_input.htm) attribute is for a Regex validation:

> Specifies the regular expression that the input's value is checked
>   against

the component does not support this,

An interesting post for you to read to better understand the reasoning behind this would be [Is there any way to change input type=“date” format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format). Bascially, it comes down to web standards.

One way  to do this would be to create your own text input component and set a placeholder:

```
<input type="text" name="input" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" pattern="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}" title="dd/mm/yyyy"/>
```

and combine with the SLDS component for [date picking](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/datepickers/)

Unfortunatelly, to my knowledge, you have to create it from scratch. Maybe someone else can share a more viable solution.

Comment: hmmm sounds doable. I'll tinker with this and let you know. Thanks a lot.